# .NET Restrict the Maximum Size of a Dataset

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis, memory, dataset

Is it possible to restrict the maximum amount of data which is loaded into a dataset. Preferably the amount of memory used. Ideally when the limit is reached an exception would be raised. The query can continue executing, but the data should not be loaded into memory. This is because we are restricted to running IIS in 32 bit mode and on a occasion the datasets are greater than 2^32. We would rather do this than recycle IIS when a limit is reached.

Comment: what mechanism are you using to *load* this dataset? can you just... check before you load it? also: are you talking about `System.Data.DataSet`? if so... frankly I'd suggest "don't do that" - `DataSet` is not your friend for efficiency, and it doesn't work well at scale. It sounds like you might want a database? (loading this kind of volume into memory is ... usually only done for very specific scenarios)

Comment: Data is loaded into the dataset via a SQL Server Query. It's loaded into System.Data.DataSet. The problem is we don't have a lot of control over the amount of data returned as the amount (Not content) is user specified.

Comment: if you absolutely have to use `DataSet` (and frankly, I think that is a terrible idea), you could always use a decorator approach to wrap the `IDataReader`/`DbDataReader`, and use your decorator to apply a row limit at the client?

Comment: if you want to recycle based o the memory used then you could use iis application pool recycling setting.1) In the Application Pools list, right-click the application pool on which you want to disable the memory limits and then click Recycling.2)In the Edit Application Pool Recycling Settings dialog box, in the Memory Based Maximums section, check the Virtual memory usage (in KB) and Private memory usage (in KB) checkboxes, and then click Next.

Comment: and for the memory restriction, you could use RequestFiltering request limits and <httpRuntime maxRequestLength>:`<system.webServer>
     <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"  />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>  
   </system.webServer>` and `<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="500000" executionTimeout="120" />
  </system.web>`

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes the issue is resolved thank you for all your suggestions

Comment: I request you to post the solution as an answer and mark it. it will help other people who face a similar issue.